# mod_rewrite laravel using form get method

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to rewrite a URL after submitting a form using the GET method in Laravel. My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/items/search/(.*)$ /items/search?m_id=%1 [QSA, L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Having submitted the form the URL still looks like this:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/search?m_id=357

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: _“Having submitted the form the URL still looks like this”_ - and why would you expect anything else to happen? That _is_ how browsers submit GET forms.

Comment: should it not go from http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/search?m_id=357 to http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/search/357?

Comment: No, why should it? `http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/search?m_id=357` is the request URL the browser creates when you submit the form. And your rewriting does not contain anything that would change that in any way.

Comment: You have to know that mod_rewrite does not rewrite the input, it is just rewrite the access path.

Comment: yeah I think I understand it a little better now. I did look at this article http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/using-modrewrite-form-parameters which also helped.

Answer (score 1):

I only just got back round looking into this. In the end I used javascript's onsubmit function to rewrite the URL

```
onsubmit="window.location.href=this.action + '/' + encodeURIComponent(this.elements['m_id'].value); return false;"
```